# Google authentication with Firebase and Jetpack Compose

Tags: firebase, kotlin, firebase-authentication, android-jetpack-compose, google-identity

I'm using Kotlin, Android Studio and Jetpack Compose

**What I want to do:**

After the button click, I would want to register the user using google authentication and firebase

**What I've tried to do:**

I've tried to follow [Firebase Auth Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/google-signin?hl=en&authuser=0), but it's really hard to understand as it often sends me back to the [Google Documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/one-tap/android/get-saved-credentials?authuser=0), which isn't helpful either in the case of Jetpack Compose.

I couldn't find any up to date videos or guides explaining this implementation. It would be awesome if someone could explain how to start with it.

Comment: This [article](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/how-to-authenticate-to-firebase-using-google-one-tap-in-jetpack-compose-60b30e621d0d) will help for sure, as it uses Google Identity One Tap together with Jetpack Compose. Here is also the corresponding [repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/FirebaseSignInWithGoogle).

Answer (score 0):

```
val context = LocalContext.current
val token = stringResource(R.string.default_web_client_id)
val launcherNav = rememberLauncherForActivityResult(
    contract = ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()
) {
    navController.navigate(Screen.MainScreen.route)
}
val launcher = rememberLauncherForActivityResult(
    contract = ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(),
) {
    val task =
    try {
        val account = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(it.data)
            .getResult(ApiException::class.java)
        val credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(account.idToken!!, null)
        FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signInWithCredential(credential)
            .addOnCompleteListener { task ->
                if (task.isSuccessful) {

                }
            }
    }
    catch (e: ApiException) {
        Log.w("TAG", "GoogleSign in Failed", e)
    }
}


Button(
    onClick = {
        val gso = GoogleSignInOptions
            .Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestIdToken(token)
            .requestEmail()
            .build()
        val googleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(context, gso)
        launcher.launch(googleSignInClient.signInIntent)
    }
) {
    Text(text = "Sign In")
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).